# How can i update content in all the header files when the drawer is opened and closed

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I am using react-navigation-drawer and react-native version 0.60.5.
I want to change the text in header file when the drawer is open and the drawer is closed.

to get the drawer open-close status I am using

`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    alert(nextProps.navigation.state.isDrawerOpen)
  }`

How can I pass the open and close status to header files throughout the app?

I want to show text Fashion Land when the drawer is closed and FL when the drawer is opened when the drawer is closed again the text in header component must be changed to Fashion Land as shown in below image.
[image]

Comment: are you using `react-navigation` header or your own?

Comment: i am using my own header

Comment: So can you provide some code in your question

Comment: do you want me to keep drawer code?

Comment: yes, keep that.

Comment: `<Header
          navigation={this.props.navigation}
             title={this.state.sideMenuValue ?("FL"):('Fashion Land')}
            icon='menu'
            onPressMenu={this.onPressMenu}
          />`
when i clicked icon changed the text but the menu close method is in side menu and open menu is in my main screen. 
How can i get it in my main screen